# Answers that are really comments/comments that are really answers

Tags: support, answers, comments

In the flagging dialog box, there is a way to indicate that an answer is not really an answer, but actually a comment.

What about the reverse case? Are flags encouraged that indicate that a comment is actually an answer to the problem? If we read comments that actually propose a solution to the problem, should we flag them as "not a comment" for a moderator to reclassify as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are flags encouraged that indicate that a comment is actually an
>   answer to the problem?

Sure, but it would be faster to simply `@` the commenter and tell them to make their comment an answer. That's what we would do; it is all we *can* do, per my answer to your second question.

> If we read comments that actually propose a solution to the problem,
>   should we flag them as "not a comment" for a moderator to reclassify
>   as an answer?

We do not have the ability to switch comments to answers; we can only switch answers to comments (and I've done that a fair number of times). All we can do in that case is simply `@` the commenter to ask them to add their comment as an answer. Veterans of Stack Exchange typically oblige, but people new to the culture typically don't and we are stuck.

Comment: That was my core question: I knew you had the ability to turn answers into comments, and didn't know if you had the reverse superpower.

Comment: I've thought the same thing. It's kind of an awkward social situation. There's a nice answer there for the posting - so that it fits "our" vision of how the site should be structured, but we are trained to not speak for others - let them get credit for their "answer".